# "growth of " VS "a growth of" VS "a growth rate of"

Tags: definite-article

> 1. The industry experienced positive growth of about two percent in 2015.
> 2. The industry experienced **a** positive growth of about two percent in 2015.
> 3. the industry experienced **a positive growth rate** of about two percent in 2015.

I think of three scenarios where I have always puzzled about the possible addition of "a" before growth. Which one is good?

Comment: I don't think #2 is correct English.

Comment: I think #1 is just a shorthand version of #3 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 3) are certainly correct. 2) could also make sense, but I would prefer 1) over 2) in most cases.

1) Growth is generally not a countable thing. When an organism or an economic entity experiences growth, it is not a single discrete occurrence. Accordingly, one might say, "The industry experienced growth."

2) However, the word "growth" might serve as a synonym for a period of growth, which might be the case in the second sentence. In this case, the word growth has an indefinite article to allow comparison of one "growth", or period of growth, to another. This is a somewhat nonstandard definition of "growth".

3) In the third sentence, the growth rate of a particular industry is one single object. Here "growth" is a noun adjunct modifying the noun "rate", and the indefinite article "a" applies to "rate." The sentence is really about a rate. What kind of rate? A growth rate.